# mysql_field_name equivalent pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to upgrade my code from mysql to pdo. When I am changing mysql_name_field to equivalent pdo. I stuck off. Check my old code.

This is in manage data class:

```
$result=$this->query($query);
$x=$this->cols_count($result);
$heading[]=$this->column_name($result);
print_r($heading);die();
```

and column_name function in data class. Manage data class inherits data class. See the column name function.

```
function column_name($result) {
    $row=$this->stmt->getColumnMeta($result);
    return $row;
}
```

it returns only one column name while I want all column names from the table.

Comment: Why not just use the keys from the first result row?

Comment: please explain. I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 5):

The [getColumnMeta()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) returns metadata for a column in a result set (the 0-indexed column from your result). Also, from the documentation:

**Warning**
This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.

**Warning**
Not all PDO drivers support PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()

What makes it not a very good approach. Instead, you can use query "SHOW COLUMNS from table" and retrieve all columns information. Alternatively, if you still want to use the `getColumnMeta()`:

```
function column_name() {
   $results = $this->query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0');
   for ($i = 0; $i < $results->columnCount(); $i++) {
      $col = $results->getColumnMeta($i);
      $columns[] = $col['name'];
   }
   return columns;
}
```

Not able to test now, but I think it will give some idea. Hope it helps,